# How can a project under the private node be moved to the shared node?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a project which is under the Private projects node in Dynamics AX. I want to move that to the Shared projects node. When I try to drag it to the Shared projects node it is asking me to delete the project and create a new one under the Shared Projects node. Is there any way I can achieve this without deleting and by just moving?

Comment: But I need to delete the existing private project right? Otherwise it might say duplicate object?

Comment: Oh ok. Then I will create a new shared project as you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a shared project with the same name as the private project and then move or copy the contents of the private project to the shared project.

Comment: You can check-in to TFS the new project and the deletion action of the old one if you want to keep the historic in source control.

Answer (score 1):

In AX, if you are not using any source control, when you have a private project and you drag & drop it on shared, it will move the project. When you will drag & drop one from shared to private, it will copy the project.

If you have TFS a VCS, it will delete and create because the private project XPO will have a new name. In your local repository, your private project os prefixed with your username. It will lost the prefix going shared.